# Outlook and Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

can you please help my by my Outlook Powershell Problem?

```
> $olSaveType = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType" -as
> [type] 
> 
> Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" $Outlook =
> New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application $Namespace =
> $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
> 
> $EmailsInFolder= $NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Items
> $EmailsInFolder | ft SentOn, Subject, Sensitivity -AutoSize -Wrap
> 
> foreach ($EmailInFolder in $EmailsInFolder)        {
> $EmailInFolder.Subject = "Test" }
```

When I run the script it works fine.
But when I start later on outlook and close outlook it comes an message for each mail where the subject will change.

[image]

> The property of an email „” has changed. Would you like to save the
>   changes in your message?  Yes / No

How I get rid of the outlook message?

If the email in a special folder I like to change the email subject with the PowerShell script. Without any interaction with the user or messages from outlook.

Regards
Stefan

Comment: Could you translate the error into english?

Comment: I put the translation into the question

Comment: Can you avoid Interops and Outlook and save yourself that hassle with [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6)?

Comment: Your code doesn't show the full foreach loop. Do you call ```$EmailInFolder.Save()``` somewhere inside?

Comment: foreach ($EmailInFolder in $EmailsInFolder)       
 { $EmailInFolder.Subject = "Test" }

Thats the full foreach Loop. I will add $EmailInFolder.Save()